# Reload datatable after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I use JQuery dataTable version 1.9. I need to reload a datatable after ajax success because I filter the elements after my query so the pagination shows all elements and not just the "real" ones filtered after the query.
I know it is wrong to do this but I can only check after the query

Here it seems that there are no elements

[image]

But when scrolling through the pagination the elements are there

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use setInterval for reloading the datatable after ajax reuqest

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#tableid').DataTable({
 });
}, 300);
```

Comment: i'm using your code in fnDrwCallback.... but i have this alert: DataTables warning (table id = 'pro'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable. To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: this problem happen when you make many then one call $().DataTable({})

Comment: i think you need to add "retrieve: true"

Comment: i try to insert setInterval(function(){
            $('#mydatatable').dataTable({bRetrieve: true});
        }, 300); but in this case don't have errors but my datatable always remains the same

Comment: https://github.com/AhmedELGAMMUDI/DJANGO-DATATABLE-AND-SELECTER_USING_AJAX/blob/main/ajax_django.html    check this link

Answer (score 0):

Please test this solution

```
function refreshTable() {
  $('.dataTable').each(function() {
      dt = $(this).dataTable();
      dt.fnDraw();
  })
}
```

Comment: I have too many row.... Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reload datatable after ajax call, then, you should have the data as a list of object. Let's say it is stored in `data`
Then, reload table by

```
function reloadDataTable(tableObject, data) {
    tableObject.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
};
```